# How to loop through all img tags inside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out a way that will allow me to do a forEach loop on all `img` tags inside my component. I looked into [`findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode), but I believe it is only used to select react components?

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky if you have deep nested children, but here are some hints :

```
render() {

  return (

    {/* add a ref to root node */}
    <div ref="RootNode">
      <p></p>
      <span></span>
      <img />
      <img />
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then access the elements children this way :

```
this.refs.RootNode.children
```

React provides an API wich facilitates looping over children elements [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) like `React.Children.map` or `React.Children.forEach`.

Comment: Yes my case is with deep nested children, I can't use refs on them, as react simply doesn't render them with refs.

Comment: Then deal with DOM directly using `jQuery` on `componentDidMount` and/or `componentDidUpdate`. There is no magical way to list children.
In any case, you need to identify the root node by adding a `ref`, or an `id`.